# Direct implementation of EF Core many-to-many relationship unable to detect the related table

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-5-and-above/#direct-many-to-many-setup-normal-setup) on setting up a proper many-to-many relationship with EF Core. I've implemented what the author calls a direct relationship. Everything's been working fine until this example:

> var books = context.Books.Tags.Select(t => t.TagId).ToList()

for which VS returns an error saying that DbSet does not contain a definition for Tags. I don't understand what's causing this, as the database is implemented just fine, and querying it with MSSQL works as expected. For example, I was able to do:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Books o
JOIN BookTags ot ON ot.BooksBookId = o.TagId
JOIN Tags c ON ot.TagsTagId = c.TagId
WHERE o.BookId = 1
```

and get a list of Tags on Book with ID = 1. Ideally, I'd like to get the same result with EF Core, but I really don't understand what's broken here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load navigation properties like that.  To load books with navigation property, use:

```
var books = context.Books.Include(b => b.Tags).ToList();
```

To get the ids only, you can use:

```
var tagIds = context.Books.SelectMany(b => b.Tags).Select(t => t.TagId).ToList();
```